# Mleader style in Autocad using C#

Tags: c#, autocad

I have created a new Mleader style in autocad using C#.  I want to use it in CAD; to assign Mleader style to a leader. I have no idea regarding this. I tried this code

```
public class test
    {
        public void drawMleaders(Transaction acTrans, Database acCurDb, Document acDoc, double scale, double gap, double[] pickPont)
        {
            BlockTable acBlkTbl;
            acBlkTbl = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.BlockTableId,
                                            OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            //Open the Block table record Model space for write
            BlockTableRecord acBlkTblRec;
            acBlkTblRec = acTrans.GetObject(acBlkTbl[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
                                           OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;

         DBDictionary mlStyles = (DBDictionary)acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.MLeaderStyleDictionaryId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
        // mlStyles.UpgradeOpen();

          if (!mlStyles.Contains("MyLeaderStyle"))
           {


                MLeaderStyle dst = new MLeaderStyle();

                // MText mt = new MText();
                // mt.Contents = text;
            //dst.Name="MyLeaderStyle";
                dst.ArrowSymbolId = ObjectId.Null;
                dst.ArrowSize = 0.5 * scale;
                //dst.ContentType = 0;
                //dst.DefaultMText = "";
                dst.LandingGap = 0;
                dst.EnableBlockRotation = true;
                dst.MaxLeaderSegmentsPoints = 2;
                dst.EnableLanding = true;



                dst.PostMLeaderStyleToDb(acCurDb, "MyLeaderStyle");
                acCurDb.MLeaderstyle = dst.ObjectId;


                //dst1.Add(dst);
                acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dst, true);

            }


            MLeader lead = new MLeader();
                int i = lead.AddLeader();
                lead.AddLeaderLine(i);
                lead.AddFirstVertex(i, new Point3d(pickPont[0], pickPont[1], 0));
                lead.AddLastVertex(i, new Point3d(pickPont[0] + 5, pickPont[1] + 5, 0));
                //lead.MLeaderStyle = acCurDb.MLeaderstyle;
                acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(lead);
                acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(lead, true);


            }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. It might help to say what specific error you're getting or different behaviour you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the leader.MLeaderStyle property to the MLeader style ObjectId.
You can get it from the MLeaderStyle dictionary if already exists or from the PostMLeaderStyleToDb return value if create it

```
        ObjectId mlStyleId;

        DBDictionary mlStyles = (DBDictionary)acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.MLeaderStyleDictionaryId, OpenMode.ForRead);
        if (mlStyles.Contains("MyLeaderStyle"))
        {
            mlStyleId = mlStyles.GetAt("MyLeaderStyle");
        }
        else
        {
            MLeaderStyle dst = new MLeaderStyle();
            dst.ArrowSymbolId = ObjectId.Null;
            dst.ArrowSize = 0.5 * scale;
            dst.LandingGap = 0;
            dst.EnableBlockRotation = true;
            dst.MaxLeaderSegmentsPoints = 2;
            dst.EnableLanding = true;
            mlStyleId = dst.PostMLeaderStyleToDb(acCurDb, "MyLeaderStyle");
            acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dst, true);
        }

        MLeader lead = new MLeader();
        int i = lead.AddLeader();
        lead.AddLeaderLine(i);
        lead.AddFirstVertex(i, new Point3d(pickPont[0], pickPont[1], 0));
        lead.AddLastVertex(i, new Point3d(pickPont[0] + 5, pickPont[1] + 5, 0));
        lead.MLeaderStyle = mlStyleId;
        acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(lead);
        acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(lead, true);

        acTrans.Commit();
```